# Running Ruby programs in Atom

Tags: ruby, atom-editor

I installed Atom and the script package, wrote a Ruby test program, saved it as hello.rb, pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to execute, and got the error message `'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I thought the script package included Ruby and multiple other grammars. Is there something else I need to do before I can run programs?

Comment: It is clear from your error message that you are working on Windows platform - which is good.   But to be honest of the two leading modules I see in Atom right now to support this - 'Script' and 'Build' - neither of them are perfect and I would consider using a different editor for Ruby.   If you are a real newbie, I might consider one of the new online code editing environments like Cloud 9.

Comment: Also, did Matt Bogen below answer your question?  If so, please mark his answer as so - else leave some comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't run my code from Atom, but I think a likely cause of your problem is not having Ruby itself installed on your machine. Macs have Ruby installed from the factory, but Windows machines typically don't.

Check out http://rubyinstaller.org/. It's a simple tool for installing Ruby in a Windows environment.